# Trigger Not Wokring: Error: Compile Error: Expression cannot be assigned at line -1 column -1

Tags: trigger

Can Someone help me with this trigger : It is not working

```
trigger ControlOpportunityStage on Line_Item__c (after update) {
    List<Opportunity> parentlist = new List<Opportunity>();
    List<Opportunity> opportunityId = new list<Opportunity>();

    for(Line_item__c lirecord : [SELECT Opportunity__r.id, Opportunity__r.StageName 
                             from Line_item__c
                             where Line_item__c.Opportunity__c <> null]){

        for(Opportunity opt : parentlist)
            if(Opportunity.StageName != Line_item__c.Stage__c)
                Opportunity.StageName = "Line_item__c.Stage__c;
                opportunityId.add(opportunity.Id);
        {
             if(opportunityId != null & opportunityId.Size()>0)
             update opportunityId;
        }     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You've declared:

```
List parentlist = new List();
List opportunityId = new list();
```

It should be:

```
List<Opportunity> parentlist = new List<Opportunity>();
List<ID> opportunityId = new List<ID>();
```

You have this block of code (I just formatted the section, did not alter anything):

```
for(Line_item__c lirecord : [SELECT Opportunity__r.id, Opportunity__r.StageName FROM Line_item__c WHERE Line_item__c.Opportunity__c <> null]) {
  for(Opportunity opt : parentlist)
    if(Opportunity.StageName != Line_item__c.Stage__c)
      Opportunity.StageName = "Line_item__c.Stage__c;
      opportunityId.add(opportunity.Id);
```

You need to use enclosing brackets and quotes. You have:

```
for(Opportunity opt : parentlist)
```

It should be:

```
for (Opportunity opt : parentlist) {
```

You have a random " in:

```
Opportunity.StageName = "Line_item__c.Stage__c;
```

**Honestly, it seems like you made no effort to follow syntax at all and just hoped someone would make it compilable for you**....I guess I've been tricked.

Comment: Yup, you spent more time on your answer than the OP did in writing the code and posting the question....

Comment: There are, I suppose, up to 18 errors, depending on your view point on errors (I'm pretty strict, so...).

Comment: A for effort, but I agree with Eric.  You did the OP a favor.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You have not needed double quotes sign. 
Opportunity.StageName = Line_item__c.Stage__c;

Comment: I am a new Salesforce Admin, I have no experience with Apex, and I am very new to the language, I was directed to this site for assistance and I appreciate the help.

Comment: Furthermore the corrections do not make it work...I still get an error after using the trigger below:


Expression cannot be assigned at line -1 column -1

Comment: @RamSidhu, I suggest you start with "Hello World". It will be the best solution.